# "npx prisma db seed" command got Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

*****this is package.json file*****

when I am running "npx prisma db seed" i am getting this error
An error occured while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts

```
  {
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/layout": "^1.5.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.7.2",
    "@dh-react-hooks/use-raf": "^0.9.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.6.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "easy-peasy": "^5.0.4",
    "format-duration": "^1.4.0",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-howler": "^5.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "reset-css": "^5.0.1",
    "swr": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-superjson-next": "^0.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.2",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "prisma": "^3.6.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },

"prisma": {
  "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *Next.js* I have solved this issue running the following command:

```
npm install -D typescript ts-node @types/node
```

Then I added in *package.json* file, right **after** `"devDependencies": {},`:

```
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  }
```

After that I was able to run the command below without issues (and the DB has been populated):

```
npx prisma db seed
```

**Command output:**

> Environment variables loaded from .env
> Running seed command `ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts` ...

> The seed command has been executed.

*Prisma version: 4.9.0*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, install `ts-node` by typing  `npm install -g ts-node` to your terminal.

then in your package.json file

add this

```
"prisma": {
"seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts"
},
```

taken from:
[https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database]

Comment: I first installed ts-node to dev dependancies as suggested in another answer, it didn't work for me. Installing globally worked, though, I am weary of installing anything globally. I may take some time to understand this further, but either way, this post worked along with installing the type defs.  ~ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following the prisma [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database)

In step 3:

> Add `typescript`, `ts-node` and `@types/node` development dependencies:

In your `package.json`, there's no `@types/node` in your `devDependencies`, so I think you have to install it then try seeding again

```
npm install -D @types/node
```

Comment: i did it but still not working.......it comes with the same error

Comment: @nattyeth You should update `prisma` to latest version, I also faced this issue when using older version.